# Combine the all custom array value into one string observable

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to return single string once map the whole array object.

Here it's below code that combine my custom array input to string but it's emit each value alone instead map into single block of string(concatenation of string).

```
const exampleInfo: GithubInfo = {
  name: "Hello",
  login: "Hello1",
  description: "TypeScript dev",
  repos: [{ project: "ts", star: 5 }, { project: "js", star: 5 }]
};

const repos = from(gitHubInfo["repos"]);

const reposeDetial = repos.pipe(
  map(val => `${val.project},${val.star}`))
 .subscribe(val => {
 console.log(val); // emit `ts,5` ,`js,5` instead in single block `ts,5,js,5`
});
```

Comment: If your goal is to emit just 1 repos array instead of sequence of repos, then you can use "of" instead of "from" in the "from(gitHubInfo["repos"])"; and change your following mapping accordingly.
Otherwise, if "from" is just an example, and you indeed are getting a sequence of repos from your observable, you can use the "reduce" operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concat your emitted data at the end of your operators chain, you can use reduce. It will accumulate all your stream into one single value:

```
const exampleInfo: GithubInfo = {
  name: "Hello",
  login: "Hello1",
  description: "TypeScript dev",
  repos: [{ project: "ts", star: 5 }, { project: "js", star: 5 }]
};

const repos = from(gitHubInfo["repos"]);

const reposeDetial = repos.pipe(
  map(val => `${val.project},${val.star}`)),
  reduce((acc, value) => acc.concat(value), '')
).subscribe(val => {
 console.log(val); // emit `ts,5,js,5`
});
```